# vue-froala-wysiwyg images not working - Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, vue.js, wysiwyg, froala

Im using [vue-froala-wysiwyg](https://github.com/froala/vue-froala-wysiwyg) and there is a little problem with its image upload system: it does not works.

[image]

It generates the next code:

```
<img src="blob:http://localhost:8000/69573c0e-5441-4a0b-b5b2-f00e529ea9a1" class="fr-fic fr-dib" style="width: 300px;">
```

I'm printing the content like this:

```
{!! $thread->content !!}
```

And this is the content itself (taken from the database):

```
<p><img src="blob:http://localhost:8000/69573c0e-5441-4a0b-b5b2-f00e529ea9a1" style="width: 300px;" class="fr-fic fr-dib"></p><p><br></p><p>Carga por favor, no me hagas esto Laravel &lt;/3</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the response from the upload function is not setup properly.  It should be responding with a link like ( JSON ):

```
{ "link": "path/to/image.jpg" }
```

It looks like the response is blog:{link} right now...